# Creating Customized control

Tags: c#, ide

Is there any toolbox that I can use to create a something like the picture attached in visual studio (c#)??.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a propertygrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` from the toolbox